# datagridview with multi tables with where id parameter

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I want to use 2 tables for 1 datagridview with an employee ID search included. Therefore I wrote an query something like this:

```
string queryGrid = "SELECT Requests.Title, Requests.Description, Requests.Create_Date,  Requests.End_Note, Is_Active.Activity  FROM Requests r RIGHT JOIN Is_Active ia ON  r.Is_ActiveID=ia.Is_ActiveID WHERE r.EmployeeID='" + Header.id.ToString() + "'";
```

but it seems not working and I know that I'm not good in sql. Here are the tables that I want to use:

```
Requests      |Is_Active
____________  |__________
Title         |Is_ActiveID 
Description   |Activity
Create_Date   |
End_Note      |
Is_ActiveID   |
```

I want all info in request but instead of Is_ActiveID, I want to see Activity info. Thanks whoever will answer my question...

P.S:
I did use datatable & dataadapter to use it as datasource in gridview. Here are the error message with my query:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in  System.Data.dll

Additional information: The multi-part identifier "Requests.Title" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "Requests.Description" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "Requests.Create_Date" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "Requests.End_Note" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "Is_Active.Activity" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join is incorrect. You aliased your tables, so use the alias. Try the following:

```
SELECT r.Title, r.Description, r.Create_Date, r.End_Note, ia.Activity  
FROM Requests r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Is_Active ia 
ON  r.Is_ActiveID=ia.Is_ActiveID 
WHERE r.EmployeeID=?
```

If every Request has a corresponding Is_Active record, change the join to INNER JOIN for better performance.

Comment: Thanks, but it do not refresh the gridview at load of the screen even I did write in load. It will refresh the gridview when close and open the same form. For ex.: Customer panel(with gridview) is empty -> newrequest.show(); customer.close() -> newrequest.close(); customer.open() gridview filled.

Comment: I think that is a separate question. If the above query returns the correct data, but it is not being displayed, then you have in issue with your form code. Please post a new question with your c# code and we will help you. BTW, Form.Load might be a little early for the datagridview control. Try the Form.Shown event.